# SQL Server Query Syntax needed

Tags: sql-server

I have a situation, where I need to pull data from 2 tables , and this is the requirement

**Table1**

**Filename | FileUpLoaded**

**Table2**

**ID | Filename | InsertedDate**

I would like to get the status of files Loaded - with two conditions
Join two tables on Filename where

1. FileUpLoaded = 1 (loaded)
2. Count of ID for today is +/- 10% (somewhere near) the count of ID from 3 days before

So that helps me understand the it is loaded correctly.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: User "Order By" and then use TOP XXX where XXX is the count of IDs.  You will need to use a query with two Selects to get the Count of ID.

Comment: Sounds like you could use a select statement where in the WHERE clause you use WHERE EXISTS (SELECT ... FROM ... ) A bit hard to write a good example without knowing anything about your tables.

Comment: select distinct convert(date,H.InsertedDate),count(ID)[Count] from Table2 (nolock) H,
Table1 R
where H.Filename = R.Filename 
and R.FileUpLoaded = 1
and convert(date,H.InsertedDate) = getdate()
group by convert(date,H.InsertedDate)
having count(ID) < 
(select ((count(ID)) * 0.1) from Table2 (nolock) H where convert(date,InsertedDate) >= DATEADD(day,-7, getdate()))      I tried this query but it doesnt seem to be correct

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a very odd set of processing logic. Have you got a rationale behind what you are trying to achieve that would explain it? I suspect simply writing the query for you wouldn't advance your understanding much.

That said, here's the query for the most part anyway, I assume that your tables are small enough that this will perform reasonably well without having to invoke WINDOW functions:

```
DECLARE @QueryDate DATETIME = GETDATE();
DECLARE @DaysBefore INT = 3;

SELECT
    FileName    =   Table1.Filename,
    OnThisDay   =   COALESCE(OnQueryDate.Tally, 0),
    BeforeThisDay   =   COALESCE(BeforeQueryDate.Tally, 0)
FROM
    Table1
        OUTER APPLY 
        (
            SELECT Tally = COUNT(1) FROM Table2 WHERE Table2.FileName = Table1.Filename AND 
                Table2.InsertedDate BETWEEN CONVERT(date, @QueryDate) AND DATEADD(DAY, 1, CONVERT(date, @QueryDate))
        ) AS OnQueryDate,
        OUTER APPLY 
        (
            SELECT Tally = COUNT(1) FROM Table2 WHERE Table2.FileName = Table1.Filename AND     
                Table2.InsertedDate BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY,-@DaysBefore,CONVERT(date, @QueryDate) AND CONVERT(date, @QueryDate)
        ) AS BeforeQueryDate
WHERE
    Table1.FileUploaded = 1
    AND
    ... Whatever conditions you want to apply here.
```

Comment: Thanks Steve, I am not that good at SQL but have a requirement to get this.. so tried whatever I could..                                                                           I shall try applying this logic on my tables and let you know how it goes...    Thank you